# Pass object into process Python

Tags: python, object, process, multiprocessing

I have a program with an object `trm` of `terminal`, and `terminal` has the function `write()` which writes a string to a GUI. I am passing this object into a an object of `multiprocessing.Process`, however when I call the function `write()` within this process, it doesn't work. Nothing happens.
What is going on?

Comment: Where is your code? What is a `terminal`? Does it have a `flush()` method and have you tried calling it after `write()`?

Comment: @mhawke I'd love to show you my code, but unfortunately it is a large project and the code is heavily modulated and trying to show you "my code" isn't efficient. However I can say `terminal` is A GUI with tkinter, so maybe tinter isn't safe when it comes to the multiprocessing module

Comment: But surely you can come up with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the `trm` object as the target of the `multiprocessing.Process`? As long as I know, the target should be a callable. In this case, you should be passing `trm.write` as the target of the process, not `trm`. If you need to pass arguments to the target, you can pass through the args parameter, which gets a tuple of arguments that will be passed to your target.